# How to detect page overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I know you can set the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property in CSS to determine what the page *does* on overflow, but I was wondering if there was any way to listen for page overflow using pure javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by comparing `offsetHeight` and `scrollHeight`

```
var div = document.getElementById('main');
console.log(div.scrollHeight);
console.log(div.offsetHeight);
```

The element should have `overflow: auto/scroll` css property.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5vc8/)    (*add content in the div to check*)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery

```
$("element").css("overflow");
```

or

```
$("element").css("overflow-x");
```

I recommend you the 2nd example, because it should work in most browsers.

Comment: Wouldn't this just return the _value_ of the `overflow` property? I want to detect if the page has enough content to where it overflows.